# Thunderbird sub folders grayed out after migrating to new mail server (postfix,dovecot,docker)

Tags: postfix, dovecot, imap, thunderbird

I migrated my old mail server (postfix,dovecot,...) to a new one (same services but with docker).

In addition I changed the mail dir of the single account from `.../domain.tld/name/Maildir` to `.../domain.tld/name` (removed Maildir).
I really just copied (tar & rsync) all data (including all dovecot files like dovecot.index etc).

The new server works fine (receiving,sending,ssl,dkim...all works).
But subfolders of the account are grayed out and the thunderbird log tells me that `\Subscribed \NonExistent` flags are set for the folders in the IMAP protocol. Folders like INBOX work.

Current state:

- Old server is inactive, i could start it again but without mails from today
- New server is running but with \NONEXISTENT subfolders

Two ideas:

1. I found the doveadm-sync tool now. Should I just try to sync both and hope the tool somehow repairs the folder problem?
2. Should I just remove the dovecot files (which ones?) and hope it rebuilds the index and finds the folders?
3. Should I backup (one direction sync) the old to the new now (as I should have done from the beginning I guess). I can simply copy the new mails on client side (in thunderbird).
4. any better ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Step 1: Make a backup to a fresh folder and then do 3. Step 2: learn from this.

Comment: Step 1: ok, 100% votes for point 3 at the moment :)
Step 2 is already done!